# Change motherboard, now computer boots to Grub2 and not Windows 10

Tags: motherboard, bios, multi-boot, grub2

So I upgraded my LGA 775 setup's motherboard to Asus P5E. My main hard disk has both Windows 10 and Ubuntu 14.something installed. With my old motherboard the computer booted straight to Windows 10 by default. However, with this new board the computer boots into Grub2 and is unable to boot from there to Ubuntu (it stops into blinking **_**). I can see "Windows 10" in Grub2, but if I try to to load it, it doesn't boot into Windows 10, but gives the errors:

> error: no such device: CEC8392CC83913E5
>   Setting partition type to 0x83
>   error: invalid signature
>
> Press any key to continue...

and returns to Grub2.

What should I do to be able to boot into Windows 10 again?

---

Managed to be able to fix booting into Ubuntu by booting into Ubuntu's recovery mode and then updating Grub2.

So now I can boot to Ubuntu (the computer still boots by default to Grub2). However, updating Grub2 also made the Windows 10 option disappear :/

Answer (score 0):

You probably will have to reinstall grub2 using a live distro, this is going to be useful https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RecoveringUbuntuAfterInstallingWindows

The problem has probably been caused by the fact that the new cotroller on the MB is assigning different labels to the disks than the old one, and grub (which uses a static table for booting) got "confused" by that.

If the automated  system does not read the windows partition you can always do it "the terminal way".

First of all make sure to have all the partitions mounted, even the Windows one.

Generate an fstab file (use -U or -L to define by UUID or labels, respectively):

```
# genfstab -U /mnt >> /mnt/etc/fstab
```

you probably have a MBR partition table, to check it you can use:

```
# parted /dev/sdx print
```

in the case of a MBR partitioned disk you simply need to run

```
# grub-install --target=i386-pc /dev/sdx
# grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg
```

to install grub2 to the /dev/sdx disk (substitute sdx for the actual partition).

If this were to still to not work, you will have to write a custom /boot/grub/grub.cfg file.

To do that you will need the uuid of the windows partition (the /SYSTEM_RESERVED one not the C:\ drive).
Assuming the mount point for the windows bootloader is /media/SYSTEM_RESERVED/bootmgr you can:

```
# grub-probe --target=fs_uuid /media/SYSTEM_RESERVED/bootmgr
```

to get the uuid of that partition

then you will have to modify the file /etc/grub.d/40_custom by adding the following lines:

```
if [ "${grub_platform}" == "pc" ]; then
  menuentry "Microsoft Windows Vista/7/8/8.1 BIOS-MBR" {
    insmod part_msdos
    insmod ntfs
    insmod search_fs_uuid
    insmod ntldr
    search --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,msdos1 --hint-efi=hd0,msdos1 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,msdos1 "UUID"
    ntldr /bootmgr
  }
fi
```

Substituting "UUID" with the actual uuid for your partition and re-run the grub-mkconfig command as above.

This might help you modifiy your grub configuration:

https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/GRUB#Windows_installed_in_UEFI-GPT_Mode_menu_entry

If you want to use the windows bootloader, while booting windows you can just run the startup repair tool.